# Python adding elements from string

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have a string like this "1    1   3   2       1   1   1       2       1   1   1   1           1   1   1   1,5     0,33    0,66    1   0,33    0,66                        1       1   2           1   1   2               1   1   2   0,5 0,66    2               1   2   1   1   1   0       1".

How to add elements to each other in python ?

I've tried :

```
list = []
for x in str.replace(' ', ''):
    list.append(x)
sum = 0
for y in list:
    sum = sum + double(x)
```

but I'm getting errors constantly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print sum(float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in str.split(' '))
```

outputs:

```
45.64
```

Answer (score 4):

The "python-esque" way of doing it:

```
sum([float(num) for num in str.replace(',', '.').split(' ')])
```

Makes a list by splitting the string by spaces, then turn each piece into a float and add them up.

Comment: David: You have to take into account the random commas.

Comment: What's random about the commas?

Comment: David: Why not just drop the list and use generator syntax?

Comment: NB: split uses ' ' by default. No need to specify that explicitly

Answer (score 4):

Let's not be so ethno-centric.  ',' is a legitimate decimal point for many people.  Don't replace it, adapt to it using the locale module:

```
>>> s = "1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1,5 0,33 0,66 1 0,33 0,66 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 0,5 0,66 2 1 2 1 1 1 0 1"
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(0,"po")
'Polish_Poland.1250'
>>> sum(map(locale.atof, s.split()))
45.639999999999993
```

Comment: Then shouldn't the output be `45,639`?

Comment: The value 45.64 (as I write it) is the value 45.64 regardless of how it is displayed. If you needed to print it back out in the localized format, then wrap it in locale.str(), which in this case would give "45,64".

Answer (score 2):

Edit: If David's guess was right such that you need decimals:

```
>>> from math import fsum
>>> fsum(float(n) for n in input.replace(',', '.').split())
45.640000000000001
```

Note I'm using `math.fsum()` to preserve floating point loss.

Comment: Huh? You lost me. Does that mean we should use `float` instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
my_string = "1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1,5 "
            "0,33 0,66 1 0,33 0,66 1 1 2 1 1 2 "
            "1 1 2 0,5 0,66 2 1 2 1 1 1 0 1"

my_string = my_string.replace(',', '.')

value = sum([float(n) for n in my_string.split()])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, then try this:

```
list = []
for x in str.replace(',', '.').split():
    list.append(x)
sum = 0
for x in list:
    sum = sum + float(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok this worked :

```
sum(float(n) for n in str.replace(',','.').split())
```

Comment: That's identical to my answer (and many others' now it seems). Feel free to accept one of our answers!

Comment: yeah I know, you must've written yours when I was creating mine :)